# не могу разобраться со SpringData

Tags: spring, spring-data

Всем, доброго времени суток,не могу разобраться с тем как правильно написать метод для поиска нужных  мне элемементов с помощью spring data

У меня есть две сущности Event и DateException:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

    private long id;
    private String eventType;
    private String eventLocation;
    private LocalDateTime eventStartDate;
    private LocalDateTime eventEndDate;
    private String eventTime;
    private long eventCost;
    private String eventTitle;
    private String eventContent;
    private String eventLink;

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "date_exception")
public class DateException {

    private long id;
    private LocalDateTime eventDateEx;
    private Event event;

    public DateException() {
    }

    public DateException(LocalDateTime eventDateEx) {
        this.eventDateEx = eventDateEx;
    }

    ...
}
```

Как можно увидеть сущности связаны друг с другом соотношением один ко многим.

1)Теперь средствами spring data я хочу создать метод который будет искать все сущности Event у которых event_start_date <= указанной мною даты, event_end_date >= указанной мною даты а также поле связанной сущности DateException.eventDateEx *не содержало* указанной мною даты.

2) У меня получилось написать метод который будет искать все сущности Event у которых event_start_date <= указанной мною даты, event_end_date >= указанной мною даты а также поле связанной сущности DateException.eventDateEx *содержит* указанную мною дату. Метод выглядит так:

```
Page<Event> findByEventEndDateGreaterThanEqualAndEventStartDateLessThanEqualAndDateExceptions_EventDateEx(LocalDateTime data, LocalDateTime data2, LocalDateTime data3, Pageable pageable);
```

**Вопрос как переписать метод так,чтобы он искал сущности Event так как я описал это в пункте 1, и вообще можно ли так сделать?**

Comment: Рекомендую написать обычный запрос (в @Query) вместо этой "колбасы". Так будет проще и реализация, и понимание того, что она делает. И еще совет - убери весь лишний бойлерплейт код из вопроса, зачем здесь гетеры/сетеры/конструкторы/поля/аннотации и т.п.? Нет времени в это вчитываться - следовательно вероятность ответа подает...

Comment: Я думал об этом, но не сообразил как правильно написать запрос чтобы выборка шла из двух таблиц, так будет для выборки из одной таблицы : @Query("select e from Event e where e.eventStartDate <= ?1 and e.eventEndDate >= ?2")
    List<Event> findAllTodayEvents(LocalDateTime data, LocalDateTime data2); А как добавить вторую ?

Comment: Чтобы сделать запрос из двух связанных таблиц необходимо использовать [join](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_Joins): `select e from Event e join e.dateExceptions d where e.start <= ?1 and e.end >= ?1 and d.eventDateEx <> ?1`

Comment: спасибо,выручили)

Comment: Пожалуйста! ) Не забудь лишний код убрать из вопроса...